# How to use Trademark(TM) in ISO-8859-1 encoding?

Tags: asp.net

I have to use trademark(TM) in ISO-8859-1 .

I used following code use but it is not working.

```
&#153
&trade;
<sup>TM</sup>
```

Could any one suggest me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, in terms of a unicode character. [ISO-Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) doesn't contain the trademark character.

However, you can use `&trade;` which is the HTML entity for the trademark symbol, I believe. (That certainly used to work - whether it's valid HTML 5 etc I'm not sure.) Assuming it's still valid, I'd say it's preferable to use this approach anyway, instead of relying on a specific encoding's representation of the Unicode character. It's clearer to read, for one thing.

(The equivalent for ® is `&reg;`, by the way.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean in HTML, you can use `&trade;`, which should work with any encoding.

Comment: I was busy editing with the same suggestion, struggling against a 3G connection :)